# How do I add checkboxes to UIPickerView in iOS7?

Tags: checkbox, ios7, uipickerview

I have an app made for iOS6 which uses UIPickerViews where the cells contain clickable checkboxes. This is implemented by adding UIViews with UIGestureRecognizer for taps on it. When upgrading to iOS7 this does not work anymore. I tried adding UIButton as cells and noticed that taps are not registered in iOS7 but they are in iOS6.

So my question is really if one is meant to be able to add interactive elements such as buttons or checkboxes to UIPickerViews or if you are really supposed to use a UITableView for that?

Comment: My conclutions was that this isn't possible, or rather it is not mean to be done in iOS7 so I switched to using regular tables. Worked fine. I believe the app I inherited abused the iOS UI conventions as I can not find any usage of UIPickerView for multiple selection i Apple examples.